# JAXRS: No message body reader in a simple example?

Tags: jax-rs

I do not understand why this happens: when I declare explicitly the filename of the input in my annotated java class named "process", everything works perfect:

```
@GET
public static void process() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("a.pdf");
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("a.pdf" + ".exported"), menu.parseToString(file));
}
```

However, when I try to pass the file name as an argument, and configure also eclipse through run configurations to give the appropriate argument (path to the "a.pdf"):

```
@GET
public static void process(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(args[0] + ".exported"), menu.parseToString(file));
}
```

when I call the service it fails with an error:

```
Oct 09, 2014 9:44:55 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request class String[], ContentType :    
application/octet-stream.
```

I am new to jax rs. Do I miss any annotation? Thank you very much...

Comment: 1) That `public static void process("a.pdf")` is not valid Java. Please include the real code you use. 2) "pass the file name as an argument" How are you doin this using a HTTP request?

Comment: When the service is published I get a link. When I click on this link a.pdf is parsed. So when I explicitly define the file name and click the link on the published service it works. However, when I point out to the file location (a.pdf) and click on the published web service link I get the error mentioned. That's my real code btw. and 1) works/compiles great on my side...

Comment: What you write makes no sense. "When the service is published I get a link." What link? Where? I don't see any HTML that links anywhere. "when I point out to the file location". How do you do that? Summary: Please show us how you call this JAX-RS resource.

Comment: "link" = identifies the URI path template to which the resource responds. This part of code I posted is a resource which I have annotated accordingly and published it as a jax rs (see for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/ginpw/index.html to understand what do I mean by link). I am sorry if this upset you my friend. Probably yes I shouldn't have used "link" but "resource URI" instead.

Comment: I know the `@Path` annotation. Please tell us the details of the HTTP request you make. The infromation you provided so far is not enought to understand your problem.

Comment: As I explain in my initial post, when I publish the service and submit a GET request to it A. when filename is explicitly declared everything works great, B. when it is declared as the second option it fails with the before mentioned error. Why A behaves different than B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Invalid Java syntax

This

```
public static void process("a.pdf") throws IOException {
  // ...        
}
```

is not valid Java syntax. Every IDE and `javac`will complain about it. Eclipse says:

> Syntax error on token ""a.pdf"", delete this token

### `application/octet-stream` as body

It looks like you try to make a `GET` request with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` (the file you somehow 'clicked'). This has two problems:

1. A `GET` request normally as no body, it just has headers.
2. A body of bytes encoded as `application/octet-stream` can not be mapped to a `String[]` because JAX-RS has no way to know how to intepret the bytes.

### What you probably want

It looks like you want to make a `GET` request with a *file name* as a *request parameter* (that is not the sames as a *file* in the *body* of the request). You could do this:

```
GET http://example.com/service?filename=foo.pdf
```

Then a JAX-RS like the following could be used to service this request:

```
@GET
public Response service(@QueryParam("filename") String filename) {
  // use filename to open a File and do something with it
}
```

Note the use of `@QueryParam` which allows `service` to extract `filename=foo.pdf` from the request URL.

Comment: Yes you are correct about that ("a.pdf" is not needed inside process() - I deleted it from my post), however the rest stays the same and still the problem remains, why when I explicitly (hard code lets say) declare the filename jax rs is not complaining and when I try to do it by passing filename as an argument it fails? I will evaluate your proposed solution and I will get back to you. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You are *not* passing the filename as a `String` argument. Not as a path argument, not as a query parameter, and not as the request body, too. You *are* passing some bytes as `application/octet-stream`. Where do the come from? Are they the file *name* or the file *content*? Unless you provide more details about how *exactly* you make the HTTP GET request, I can only guess.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The file is on a folder on the server that hosts the jax-rs service. So when I publish the service explicitly referring to the filename, the file gets discovered when I hit the URI of the published service, however when I give as an argument the path to the filename the file resides, for some reason I get this error I mentioned. I want to know the reason that causes the error.